# How to extract partial column name and pass the value to variable in SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio-2013, ssis

[image]I am working on Excel file to load the data into sql table using SSIS VS2013.

How do I extract the column names into a temptable?

In the image attached,there is the "2017 Marketing Sales - Actual" column in the first row, I want to extract the YYYY from the column name and pass that value to a variable and update the table field with YYYY info.

Can you anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: there is no image attached.

Comment: Sorry i missed to add. Just added it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Excel Connection Manager, uncheck the "First row has column names" check box. This should allow you to access that first row. You'll need to setup a Data Flow Task using this Excel Connection Manager, followed by a derived column to extract the left 4 characters from that 1st row. Unless you somehow limit the rest of the Excel data source, you'll probably also get a lot of extraneous rows importing into your destination. Might need to do some clean up to get it down to just that year.